# First shot fired is superimposed by second shot or simply disappears after second shot and etc

Tags: python, class, pygame, updates, bullet

I am trying to resolve the cause of my triggered bullet disappearing if in a short period of seconds I fire a second bullet. I imagine that `screen.fill(GRAY)` might be a cause and it should be inside the `Class Bullet()` or maybe I need to use `all_sprites_list.update()` elsewhere.

Here is my MWE code:

```
import pygame
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
GRAY = (128,128,128)
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
class Cowboy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.image = pygame.Surface([14,20])
          self.image.fill(BLUE)
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png").convert()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      def update(self):
         self.rect.y += -3
def main():
    pygame.init()
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE) 
    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group() 
    enemies_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullet = Bullet()
    enemy = Cowboy()
    enemies_list.add(enemy)
    all_sprites_list.add(enemy)
    enemy.rect.y = 50
    enemy.rect.x = 50
    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                bullet_list.add(bullet)
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullet.rect.x = 340
                bullet.rect.y = 200
        screen.fill(GRAY)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I couldn't run your code (grey screen), but from symptoms you described my guess is that the problem is that you have only one instance of bullet, so it has only one set of parameters (like position). So instead of reusing, you should instantiate new `Bullet` instance every time it's shot. Also, you need to clean up this too (e.g. removing bullets that left the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of `Bullet`, when the mouse button is pressed and you have to invoke the `update` method of the bullets calling `update` on the `bullet_list`:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    # bullet = Bullet() <--- DELETE

    # [...]
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                # create new bullet and add it to the groups
                bullet = Bullet()
                bullet.rect.center = enemy.rect.center
                bullet_list.add(bullet)
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)

        # update the bullets
        bullet_list.update()

        # [...]
```

Comment: ThankXD! I had used all of this missing code before posting the question but maybe I haven't figured out how to combine them in the correct order of your answer. So, with your explanation, I can move forward in learning to use the pygame module correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
GRAY = (128,128,128)
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
class Cowboy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.image = pygame.Surface([14,20])
          self.image.fill(BLUE)
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self, x, y):
          pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
          self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png").convert()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.rect.x = x
          self.rect.y = y
      def update(self):
         self.rect.y += -3
def main():
    pygame.init()
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE) 
    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group() 
    enemies_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullet = Bullet(340, 240)
    enemy = Cowboy()
    enemies_list.add(enemy)
    all_sprites_list.add(enemy)
    enemy.rect.y = 50
    enemy.rect.x = 50
    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                bullet = Bullet(340, 200)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullet.rect.x = 340
                bullet.rect.y = 200
        screen.fill(GRAY)
        all_sprites_list.update()
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: My MWE code is a part of a larger code that I'm working on. So your answer worked but I am marking the other answer as resolved by elucidating the steps on how to find the cause of the error. Although you also implicitly pinpointed the cause of the error in your response by posting only the corrected code. So I also thank you for your help. @SartajAnsari ThankXD